# #define macro causing segmentation fault or something else causing segfault?

Tags: c, macros

I am using [libnfs](https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs) for C. I am calling nfs_read and it takes the size of bytes to read as a uint64_t variable. I have the size defined as a macro (#define 100). I mostly get a segfault (or sometimes some other error based on what value I choose, but always the same error for the specific value)for any size value greater than 24. I also tried changing #define to global uint64_t. I first had it in a header file and also moved it from header file to c file. But the result is always the same (if size is greater than 24), segfault.

But when I pass the value directly (as hard coded value) to the function nfs_read I do not get segfault, for any value of size (<24 or >24).

I have done fair number of projects in C before and have never faced such an error. Any idea what could be happening here. Thanks.

```
typedef struct {
  int is_nfs;
  int fd;
  struct nfs_context *nfs;
  struct nfsfh *fh;
}nfs_fd_t;

#define COUNT 100

// The open function is same as in the linked example except for I added nfs_dd_t struct to store nfs and fh
int dd_open(const char *path, int flags, mode_t mode, nfs_fd_t *nfs_fd);

ssize_t read_wrapper(nfs_dd_t *nfs_fd)
{
   char * buf = malloc(COUNT);
   int ret = dd_read(nfs_fd, buf, COUNT);
   // follow up logic
}

ssize_t dd_read(nfs_fd_t *nfs_fd, void *buf, uint64_t count)
{
  int ret;

  if ((ret = nfs_read((*nfs_fd).nfs, (*nfs_fd).fh, count, (char *)buf)) < 0) {
    errno = -ret;
    return -1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

`nfs_dd_t` is a struct containing nfs and fh. I am basically following [this example](https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs/blob/master/examples/ld_nfs.c#L178) only slightly modified for my need.

Comment: I would appreciate if you also told me why you downvoted the question so that I can at least learn what I did wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Include your full code, please.

Comment: I have added some more part of my code, hope this makes it more clear. Please let me know if this helps or I can try elaborate more. I tried to add enough without adding additional (irrelevant) parts.